# Yii Framework: Pagination with HAS_MANY, BELONGS_TO

Tags: yii

I have been facing this problem all day long.

I have 2 tables Service and Log. Each Service can have many Logs and each Log belongs to a Service.
I managed to generate the CRUD functionality for both.
Here is what I got:

app/models/Log.php

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array
    (
        'services' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Service', 'sv_ident_nr'),
    );
}
```

app/models/Service.php

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array
    (
        'logs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Log', 'sv_ident_nr'),
    );
}
```

app/controlelrs/ServiceController.php

```
/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view', array
    (
        'model' => $this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

app/views/service/view.php

```
<h1>Service: <?php echo $model->ident_nr; ?></h1>
<table class="dataGrid">
<tr>
    <th class="label"><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('proj_nr')); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->proj_nr); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="label"><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('customer')); ?></th>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->customer); ?></td>
</tr>
```

```
<h1>Comments</h1>
<?php foreach ($model->logs as $log): ?>
<div class="comment" id="c<?php echo $log->id; ?>">
    <div class="actions">
        <?php 
            echo CHtml::link('View',array($this->createUrl('../log/view', array('id'=>$log['id']))));
            echo('&nbsp');
            echo CHtml::link('Update',array($this->createUrl('../log/update', array('id'=>$log['id']))));
            echo('&nbsp');
            echo CHtml::link('Delete',array($this->createUrl('../log/delete', array('id'=>$log['id']))));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
        <?php 
            echo $log->logger;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="time">
        <?php echo date('j F Y \a\t h:i a', $log->created_at); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <?php echo nl2br(CHtml::encode($log->comment)); ?>
    </div>

</div><!-- comment -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The question is : How do I go about paginating the results in the 'foreach loop'?
Thanks

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want to use :)

Comment: then take a look at this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination

Comment: I tried that it as well. It doesn't work the way I want it. It shows an infinite number of links although I just have 5 for example.

Comment: and what way will that be? are you using CActiveDataProvider?

Comment: No. I am just retrieving the content looping through foreach $model->logs. based on the ralations between the two tables.

Comment: use an extension or cactivedataprovider (which is used by cgridview as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a CGridView, look at the [docs for CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView). It allows you to do paging, Ajax retrieval, etc while also using your own template for the data. It's well worth your time ...

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day. That is exactly what I was looking for. It is so easy to overlook some fine details if you are flying through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

based upon my discussion with you earlier I think this is what you are after.

[Yii Simple Pagination](http://shanideveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/yii-pagination-simple.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I get " Trying to get property of non-object " when tryying to access                               <?php
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
'Service' => array('index'),
$model->ident_nr,
);